# connect mono to oracle error libclntsh.so

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, oracle11g

I am new to linux ubuntu and mono runtime I tried to connect to oracle 11G as usually did in windows  **(I tried it in windows with both System.Data.OracleClient and Oracle.OracleClient and both worked fine)**
but
I get this problem in ubuntu:
System.DllNotFoundException: libclntsh.so
and this is stack trace:

```
    libclntsh.so

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.DllNotFoundException: libclntsh.so
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciCalls/OciNativeCalls:OCIEnvCreate (intptr&,System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciEnvironmentMode,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,intptr)
  at System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciCalls.OCIEnvCreate (System.IntPtr& envhpp, OciEnvironmentMode mode, IntPtr ctxp, IntPtr malocfp, IntPtr ralocfp, IntPtr mfreep, Int32 xtramem_sz, IntPtr usrmempp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciEnvironmentHandle..ctor (OciEnvironmentMode mode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciGlue.CreateConnection (OracleConnectionInfo conInfo) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionPoolManager.CreateConnection (OracleConnectionInfo info) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionPool.CreateConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionPool.GetConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at example.Default.button1Clicked (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs args) [0x0000d] in /home/danar/Projects/example/example/Default.aspx.cs:18 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent (System.String eventArgument) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent (System.String eventArgument) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent (IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, System.String eventArgument) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvents () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRaiseEvents () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.InternalProcessRequest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

and this my connection string to oracle I used System.data.oracleclient

```
string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
                        + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))"
                        + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)));"
                        + "User Id=hr;Password=hr;";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand command=new OracleCommand();
            command.Connection=conn;
            command.CommandText="select * from employee";
            OracleDataReader reader=command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                Response.Write(reader[0]+"<br>");
            }
            conn.Close();
            command=null;
            reader.Close();
            reader=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have [OCI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index.html) installed, as [per the documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/Oracle). Also, please bear in mind that Oracle Data Client is no longer supported (in Mono as well as in Microsoft .NET), so your safest bet is to [use a commercial provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7120183/3205). You're already paying well over a couple of grands for the database, what difference does several hundred make?

Comment: I think Oracle themselves provides a 100% managed version of ODP.NET, in theory that should be able to run on Mono. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/ow2011-fully-managed-odp-518049.pdf

Comment: Last time I tried to use it, it still relied on OCI and did not work outside Windows OS. Granted, that was in 2008, things might have improved. On the other hand, we're talking about Oracle...

Comment: That might have been, but for me now it worked very smoothly, I've added an answer since I couldn't find the information I wrote down anywhere online

Answer (score 0):

Update, since the original answers are 2 years old.

Just use Oracle's Managed driver. You need only that, nothing else. You can then connect directly with a simple connection string to the database.

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
    <!-- If any should be in the machine.config -->
    <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add name="OracleContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=<IP_ADDRESS>:1521/XE;PASSWORD=<PASSWORD>;USER ID=<USER_ID>;Connection Timeout=600;Validate Connection=true" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I used ServiceStack's OrmLite as ORM but it should work perfectly fine also directly if you don't want to use an ORM, or with any other. All you need to make sure is that your ORM library is using the managed driver as well and not the old one. I've written a blog post regarding a hack, where I had to change ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle to use the new managed driver. This solved all my problems.

- Blog post: http://peter.grman.at/how-to-connect-mono-in-linux-to-oracle/
- ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle.Managed NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle.Managed/
- The changes in GitHub: https://github.com/Grman-IT-Solutions/ServiceStack.OrmLite/tree/OracleManagedDataAccess